# Rails AJAX UJS Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

rails 3.0

```
 <% link_to about_path, :remote => true do %>
        About Us<span>Who we are</span>
  <% end %>


  def about
    render :update do |page|
      page[:content].replace_html :partial => 'dashboard/about'
    end
  end
```

Having issues with AJAX  in rails 3.0 Just trying to get it replace the html with a partial one clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to use the new :remote=>true that was implemented in rails 3.0.

Thanks

UPDATE:
Below is the markup I get. Also when I click it, I go to a new screen with a bunch of text and white background. Thanks again.

```
<a href="/about" data-remote="true">                About Us<span>Who we are</span> 
</a>
```

Even when trying a basic example of ajax.

Hello there

```
<%= link_to 'something, something_path, :remote=true %>
```

controller:

```
def something 
render :update do |page|
page[test].visual_effect :blind_up
end
```

Comment: Seeing errors in the log? In firebug?

Comment: What markup actually gets rendered?

Comment: What text is rendered when you click the link?

Comment: it's basically a dump of text that starts with try{. I'll post it up later, but basically once you click on the link, it tries to go to a different page and gives you a whitebackground with a bunch of text being dumped onto the screen.

Comment: Even trying a basic example of a ajax call doing <%= link_to 'something, something_path, :remote=true %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great Post on an example of using Rails3 + CRUD + UJS.

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7